# Jena, reading a model takes forever

Tags: performance, jena, xerces

I am trying to understand if a given url is an ontology or not. (by trying to read it into Jena)

Normally, non-parsable pages (404, HTML etc.) throws various exceptions and valid RDF's are parsed by Jena. But some (invalid) files takes 5-10 minutes to parse! No high CPU or RAM usage, nothing! `model.read()` never ends. (Once I've waited for an hour!)

```
try {
    Model model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
    model.read("http://dbpedia.org/page/Pizza_Deliverance"); // <- THIS LINE NEVER FINISHES!

    // It is an ontology.
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Jena can't parse it
}
```

Another code sample that hangs: *(this time Model.read is provided by an input stream)*

```
// In is an InputStream that holds http://dbpedia.org/page/Pizza_Deliverance
Model model;
try {
  model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
  model.read(in, baseUri); // <- THIS LINE NEVER ENDS.
} catch (Exception e) {
  Logger.error("Error parsing file as ontology: " + baseUri, e);
  return null;
}
return model;
```

Here is the stacktrace (if I wait to get one)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.XMLHandler.endElement(XMLHandler.java:133) ~[jena-core-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:598) ~[xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNamespaceBinder.handleEndElement(XMLNamespaceBinder.java:835) ~[xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNamespaceBinder.endElement(XMLNamespaceBinder.java:599) ~[xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endNamespaceScope(XMLDTDValidator.java:2099) ~[xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:2050) ~[xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:na]
```

**My questions:**

1. Am I missing something? Misusage etc.
2. Is there any alternative to check, if a given page (or String) is parsable as ontology?

**Edit:**
I worked around this problem, by doing parsing job in another thread and killing thread if parsing takes too long. But it is not a real solution.

**Edit 2:**

I looked into source and stack traced long running code. The problem is in `org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(boolean)` If this means anything to you.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to read an HTML page to a Jena model. In other words, you send an HTTP request for this URI with application/rdf+xml media type. (See http://wifo5-03.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/bizer/pub/LinkedDataTutorial/#Terminology for more information about content negotiation in linked data) There is a redirection mechanism for linked data resources on the web. Probably, DBpedia redirection creates a problem there, e.g. an infinite redirection loop,  or maybe there is a problem with the virtuoso RDF store underlying DBpedia. You should ask this question to dbpedia mailing list, they can help you.

As an advice, if you need to check that the given URI returns a linked data resource description, you can send simple HTTP get for a few different media types, such as application/rdf+xml, application/text+n3, etc., and then parse the retrieved response with Jena if you get any response in a specified time. Here's the example:

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet();
get.setURI(URI.create("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Pizza_Deliverance"));
get.setHeader("Accept", "text/n3");
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
```

This code returns an N3 document describing the Pizza Deliverance resource. If you try this code for your http://dbpedia.org/page/Pizza_Deliverance URI with "application/rdf+xml" media type, you will get an HTTP 406 exception. This error may mean something for you to understand the URI's type.

Comment: Actually, `org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(boolean)` exception states an error while reading the DTD file of the retrieved document. Jena's accept header "application/rdf+xml, application/xml; q=0.8, text/xml; q=0.7, application/rss+xml; q=0.3, */*; q=0.2" returns the HTML document which is annotated with RDFa. I can download DTD which is pointed in that document manually. Any error in that document (http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd)? @andys

Comment: I tried to parse the DTD file. `HttpGet get = new HttpGet(); get.setURI(URI.create("http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd")); HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); HttpResponse response = client.execute(get); HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); new DTDConfiguration().parse(new XMLInputSource("-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN", null, EntityUtils.toString(entity)));` But, got the error. `Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:601) ... at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)`

Comment: I changed my `Accept` header to request rdf in high priority and valid ontologies I get from various sources drastically incresed! Thanks for pointing that out. However, this didn't solve my problem. I downloaded the URL using `ning-async-http-library` _(my framework provides it)_ into an `InputStream` and provided Jena `model.read()` with input stream and base uri. Still parsing hangs.

Comment: I think, creating an `InputStream` does not mean that you downloaded the content of the URI. `model.read()` method actually retrieves the content from the given stream. Therefore, I think you only bypass the content negotation. But, it seems that the main problem is reading the DTD pointed out in the retrieved XHTML page.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with `http://bio2rdf.org`. When I request it with curl I see that it only returns HTML, as in your case. So I think Jena should return some kind of Unparsable-Exception as soon as it sees that it can't understand the format.

In your case the fix should be to use the correct dbpedia resource, which is `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Pizza_Deliverance` instead of `http://dbpedia.org/page/Pizza_Deliverance` (difference is `resource` vs. `page`), since `http://dbpedia.org/page/Pizza_Deliverance` is only the HTML representation for reading it in a browser.

As a more general workaround I've written the following my own `readModel`-method, which you should find here: https://gist.github.com/white-gecko/8849251. If it gets an answer with a not accepted data-type it just returns `null`.

Comment: I've just updated the code it should work now, at least it returns `null` if it can't find anything usable.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago i checked my ontologies or ontology URIs with http://www.mindswap.org/2003/pellet/demo.shtml . Maybe you can first check your url with pellet. This page also gives recommendation to your ontology complexity.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve the reading problem as below;

try using

`Model model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_RULE_INF, null);`

instead of

`Model model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();`

you can find more information about OntModelSpec types [here](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModelSpec.html).

Comment: It didn't make any changes. I just looked into source and stack traced long running code. The problem is in `org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(boolean)` (but this doesn't tell me anything at all)

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing http://dbpedia.org/page/Pizza_Deliverance and getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.XMLHandler.endElement
```

i.e. the data looks to be corrupt.

Comment: Yes, data is corrupt. However, I get that exception after **5mins**. That shouldn't be normal.

Answer (score 0):

You must put the base parameter in your read method.

```
Model model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
model.read("http://dbpedia.org/page/Pizza_Deliverance", "http://www.example.com/base/");
```

Looks that returned model URIs are relevant. 
I've checked it and it's working.

Cheers

Comment: Actually, I am downloading the file myself and providing `model.read` an `input stream` and `base uri` in my development. _(I simplified my code for question. But the provided example in question is also problematic.)_ So providing base parameter didn't solve my problem. However, if the code you provided works, what is your environment? Which java version are you using? Which VM are you using? Which OS are you working? Which xerces version are you using with Jena? Which Jena version are you using? Can you provide them?

Comment: maven dependency
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-jena</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
OS: linux ubunu 12.04
JAVA 1.7

I just want to highlight that when I tried to execute your code I had this same problem like this one which you described.

Comment: I'll investigate it. Thanks for the highlight.